# Change create xml file to : Load to datatable, using xmlreader

Tags: c#, xml, database, xmlreader

I am using C# to create a `Xml file` on a drive and then write the contents of this file to a table. But now I want to read the `Xml string` and write to a table without having to create the file and then write the contents of the file to a table.

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
string fullFilePath = path + @"\Product.xml";
string Products;

Products = getProducts();
xdoc.LoadXml(Products);
xdoc.Save(String.Format(fullFilePath));

string connetionString = null;
SqlConnection connection;
SqlCommand command ;
SqlDataAdapter adpter = new SqlDataAdapter();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
XmlReader xmlFile ;
string sql = null;

int product_ID = 0;
string Product_Name = null;
double product_Price = 0;

connetionString = "Data Source=servername;Initial Catalog=databasename;User ID=username;Password=password";

connection = new SqlConnection(connetionString);

xmlFile = XmlReader.Create("Product.xml", new XmlReaderSettings());
ds.ReadXml(xmlFile);
int i = 0;
connection.Open();
for (i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    product_ID = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[0]);
    Product_Name = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[1].ToString();
    product_Price = Convert.ToDouble(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[2]);
    sql = "insert into Product values(" + product_ID + ",'" + Product_Name + "'," + product_Price + ")";
    command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
    adpter.InsertCommand = command;
    adpter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
connection.Close();
```

Unable to read the `Xml string` inline to write into the table.

Comment: I can not find where you are actually writing teh file. I see you building the content from the DB in memory, but no write operation. The way of least modification would usually be to repalce whatever FileStream you used to save the file with a Memory Stream.

Comment: Why do you need XML at all? Why not just loop through `Products` and map the properties to the database columns?

Comment: @Christopher `xdoc.Save(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Save it to a memory stream using XmlDocument.Save(), then read it from that memory stream using DataSet.ReadXml().